# How can I change the size of equation?

Tags: fontsize

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation*}‎
‎\left\{‎ 
‎\begin{array}{ll}‎
{\small ‎-\dfrac{2S_{1}^{f}\left( \mathbf{z}_{\left(‎
‎j,l,m\right) }\right)‎ +‎ S_{1}^{2f}\left( \mathbf{z}_{\left(‎
‎j,l,m\right) }\right)‎ +‎2f}{2f\left( f+1\right) }}‎, ‎& {\tiny i\in UC_%‎
‎_{\left( j,l,m\right) }}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

This equation is very wide and I want small it. How can I do it?

The code `{\small $some formula$}` works for the formula among the text.

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable. To start with, don't use the text-mode commands `\small` and `\tiny` in math mode.

Comment: @Mico what are the math form for these code?

Comment: You already  asked the same [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342221/how-can-i-decrease-my-formula-size/342254#342254). None of the answers was useful?

Comment: Isn't this a repeat of your [earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342221/5001)?

Comment: @Mico: With a concrete example, now.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. you are right, this question is repeat of my earlier question. I used the same method that you proposed for past question and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only repeat my answer to your previous post, with this concrete example.
Apart from the size problem, your code is excessively complex: you don't need all these `\left … \right` pairs.

Besides, there is a `cases` environment, inside which formulae are typeset in `\textstyle`. If it is too small for your needs, you can use the medium-size commands and environments from `nccmath`. Finally I added the `dcases` environment from `mathtools` (an extension of `amsmath`) which typesets its content in `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}‎
  ‎\begin{dcases}
  {‎-\frac{2S_{1}^{f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m) })‎ +‎ S_{1}^{2f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m)})‎ +‎2f}{2f( f+1) }}‎, ‎& {y i ∈ UC‎_{( j,l,m) }}
  \end{dcases}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}‎
  ‎\begin{cases}
  {‎-\mfrac{2S_{1}^{f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m) })‎ +‎ S_{1}^{2f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m)})‎ +‎2f}{2f( f+1) }}‎, ‎& {y i ∈ UC‎_{( j,l,m) }}
  \end{cases}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}‎
  ‎\begin{cases}
  {‎-\frac{2S_{1}^{f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m) })‎ +‎ S_{1}^{2f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m)})‎ +‎2f}{2f( f+1) }}‎, ‎& {y i ∈ UC‎_{( j,l,m) }}
  \end{cases}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}‎
  ‎\begin{dcases}
  {‎-\frac{2S_{1}^{f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m) })‎ +‎ S_{1}^{2f}( \mathbf{z}_{(‎‎j,l,m)})‎ +‎2f}{2f( f+1) }}‎, ‎& {y i ∈ UC‎_{( j,l,m) }}
  \end{dcases}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]